# Google Chrome Autofill security/privacy issue? (With multiple accounts on a site)

Tags: google-chrome, security, autofill, privacy

### Scenario

On site *example.com* I have 3 different accounts (e.g. *usernameA:passwordA*, *usernameB:passwordB*, *usernameC:passwordC*). I have let the browsers store them.

So the next time I go to *example.com*, the browser autofill/prefills the username and password fields of the first account (*usernameA:passwordA*). There's a dropdown list containing the other accounts (*usernameB:passwordB* and *usernameC:passwordC*.)

### Question

When the first *usernameA:passwordA* is autofill/prefilled by browser... is it known to *example.com* before I choose *usernameC:passwordC*? (if *example.com* is tracking form input fields?)

Can *example.com* know that both *usernameA* and *usernameC* are used by same person? (by tracking form input fields?)

Can *example.com* know that the browser had autofill/prefilled the form fields of currently logged-in user (which is *usernameC*) with *usernameA* & *passwordA* first, before this user manually chose *usernameC*?

---

#### Update

So it appears my question remains without any interest. Meanwhile I have tried googling this issue, and tried Chrome, Firefox and Opera forums, but haven't found anything (most probably because I am not using right terms to look for perhaps?). I'll just leave it here hoping someone in the know eventually stumbles on to it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that Browsers do not sent the `<input>` fields of login and passwords to the sites until after submission via `<form>` so I think it's a safe practise.